# How to get users list in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, ion-auth

I am trying to get list of users from Users table in codeigniter. My problem is that if am using following code than try to print out the result, it's giving me blank array while printing query using `last_query()` function and running this query in phpmyadmin is giving correct result.

My code in model

```
$data = $this->db->select('u.*')
                    ->from('users u')
                    ->join('users_groups ug','ug.user_id = u.id')
                    ->join('groups g','g.id = ug.group_id')
                    ->where('g.id',7)
                    ->get()
                    ->result();
```

this code is giving me blank array then what i did is print the query using following code

```
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

and this is what query was

```
SELECT `u`.* FROM `users` `u` JOIN `users_groups` `ug` ON `ug`.`user_id` = `u`.`id` JOIN `groups` `g` ON `g`.`id` = `ug`.`group_id` WHERE `g`.`id` = 7
```

which is working fine. but i am trying to print the data using `print_r($data)`
is giving me blank array.

Can anyone tell me what can be the issue ?

**edited**

My full model code.

```
<?php 
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Technician_model extends CI_Model {

public function _consruct(){
    parent::_construct();
}

function getData(){
    $data = $this->db->select('u.*')
                    ->from('users u')
                    ->join('users_groups ug','ug.user_id = u.id')
                    ->join('groups g','g.id = ug.group_id')
                    ->where('g.id',7)
                    ->get()
                    ->result();
     return $data;
}

function getRecord($user_id){
    $record = $this->db->get_where('users',array('id'=>$user_id))->row();
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($record);
    exit;
    return $record;
}

function addModel($data){

    if($this->db->insert('users',$data)){
        return  $this->db->insert_id();
    }
    else{
        return FALSE;
    }
}

function editModel($data,$user_id){

    $this->db->where('id',$user_id);

    if($this->db->update('users',$data)){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

function deleteModel($user_id){

    $this->db->where('id', $user_id);

    if($this->db->delete('users')){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return FALSE;
    }
 }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: `result()` returns an object, `result_array()` returns an assoc. array just try to change `result()` function to `result_array()`

Comment: but if print object using print_r(), data should be print, right ?

Comment: do you have records in your db? )))

Comment: can you show your full model code?

Comment: once try to execute same query inside database, if there you not getting any result means record does not match, you have to modify you query

Comment: I have updated code in quesetion.

Comment: if i am printing query and executing in phpmyadmin, i am getting following result.  http://nimb.ws/m0kE6q

Comment: @MukeshJakhar actually i am getting result direct execting query in phpmyadmin.

Comment: I think getRecord function is having same issue

Comment: I tried but no luck

Comment: showing me 0 as i tried to print num_rows();

Comment: what i found is that if i am joining users table with users_groups table, i am getting all the records except one which i am looking for..

And that record i didn't inserted into users table using ion_auth model. I inserted record by normal function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You may try this simple way to join table. you may try this and can
>   change `fields name` `table name` and `method` according to your
>   require.

```
public function getUser() {
    $this->db->select('users');
    $this->db->from('Users');
    $this->db->where('users_groups.user_id',1);
    $this->db->join('users_groups', 'users.id = users_groups.user_id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result_array();

   var_dump($result); // display data in array();
   return $result; 
}
```

Comment: there was mistake in database configuration. that's why i was getting issue. now its been fixed. Thnks

Answer (score 0):

Actually, at the end of 2 hrs of the journey, I found that I forgot to configure new database.

> All the answers were correct in this case.